# Fitch system, or alternatives?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, definition, natural-deduction, online-resources

Is there a good resource for how to understand the rules of a Fitch proof system, or an alternative? I'm currently trying to get a sense or how things are proved in natural deduction, which differs in that context changes are allowed / assumptions can be introduced and discharged, and so on.

Can you still make a proof using the line-by-line approach like you could in a Hilbert system? I don't really understand the usefulness of the Fitch system when it's hard to type and present outside of a handwritten diagram. Is there an "equivalent" way we can represent what's going on, perhaps, so that the Fitch system is easier to understand?

I get that an indentation level is a "new context" or an "introduced assumption" but I don't know what we're allowed to write on which lines in general, when we're allowed to discharge an assumption, when we know when we've proven something, when we are finished, etc.

Comment: Frederic Brenton Fitch, [Symbolic Logic: An introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=x4lIuAEACAAJ).

Comment: Jon Barwise and John Etchemendy, [Language, Proof and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=beKNZwEACAAJ).

Comment: I suppose I have answered some of this in chat, but there is an additional point to be made. Hilbert-style is to Fitch-style what assembly language is to C/Java/Python. In Hilbert-style, you have just line-by-line in the same way that assembly code has no concept of `if` or `for` structures/loops. In Fitch-style, you have the concept of subcontexts, such as `if` or `forall` contexts, which simply make everything user-friendly. Sure, it is harder to explain, but it is way easier to come up with and write down than a Hilbert-style proof.

Comment: [Online](http://www.proofmood.com/index_en.php) (but many others).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thank you very very much for posting that. I had been trying in vain to find that website for a long time now. I suspect they had changed the website name, because I do not recognize the name, but the rabbit is exactly the same!

Comment: @user21820 - you are welcome :-)

Comment: You can see also [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/about/) as well as [Natural deduction](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). And [forall x](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/).

Comment: May I remind you of the link https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/ that I recommended to you yesterday? It compares several ways of presenting natural deduction proofs.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I used to recommend forallx but stopped after at least two students got the same misunderstanding from it; page 156 of [forallxyyc](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) says "First, we have names. In FOL, we indicate these with lowercase italic letters. For instance, we might let ‘b’ stand for Bertie, or let ‘i’ stand for Willard." and so page 245 to 256 give an incorrect ∀-Intro rule, because it did not exclude names in axioms.

Comment: If your motivation for learning logic is to be able to write mathematical proofs, you might consider my DC Proof 2.0 freeware and accompanying tutorial. It is based on a simplified version of FOL, more like that typically used in say real analysis or abstract algebra. Download at http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: @DanChristensen I've seen that before but I don't have Windows at my disposal (I'm on a Mac)

Comment: It is possible to run it on a Mac if it has a Windows emulator. I have sat with a Mac user as he downloaded, installed and ran my program on his machine all within a minute or two. It might be worth your while to get a Windows emulator. You might be able to get one free from https://www.winehq.org/  If you want to write mathematical proofs, my program may be best place to start learning the required logic and basic methods of proof.

Answer (score 2):

A reference that might rapidly get you past concerns with using Fitch-style natural deduction is the *forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic* text and the corresponding general-use, Fitch-style proof checker. See links below.

For example, consider a proof of disjunctive syllogism: $¬A, A ∨ B ∴ B$.

Here is how the proof checker might allow you to prove this:

[image]

There are two options: TFL (Truth Functional Logic) and FOL (First Order Logic). They work for general purpose questions and not only the problems in the text. The software resolves formatting issues with the indented subordinate proofs and provides an ability to check along the way to make sure mistakes have not been made.

The text provides a slightly different proof in section 19.2 as well as providing an introduction to the other rules available in natural deduction along with an introduction to formal logic.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/